# The probability current of the complex scalar field, using the Noether theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, complex-numbers, noethers-theorem

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#Field_theory_version), then the Noether current for

$$
L= \eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \phi^* \partial_\nu \phi - m^2\phi^*\phi
$$

with invariant transformations:

$$
\phi\to e^{i \theta}\phi\\
\phi^*\to e^{-i\theta}\phi^*
$$

gives the probability current:

$$
j^\nu=i\left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu} \phi^* - \frac{\partial \phi^*}{\partial x^\mu} \phi \right)\eta^{\mu\nu}
$$

I am new to the Noether theorem and I am not sure how to work out the details of the proof.

The wikipedia link states, as the starting point:

> In the limit when the phase θ becomes infinitesimally small, δθ, it may be taken as the parameter ε, while the Ψ are equal to iψ and −iψ*, respectively.

Already, I do not understanding this result. My understanding of this statement is that one needs to take the limit of $\theta$ as follows:

$$
\lim_{ \theta \to 0} e^{i\theta}\phi=\lim_{\theta \to 0} (\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)\phi \to \phi\\
\lim_{ \theta \to 0} e^{-i\theta}\phi^*=\phi^*
$$

But I do not see how $\delta \theta$ implies $\phi \to i\phi$ and $\phi^*\to -i\phi^*$?

Comment: It is more appropriately called the charge current.

Answer (score 1):

Noether's Theorem is written in terms of the generators of the symmetry transformation, in other words you have to use a small parameter $\theta$, for which the transformations look like:

$$\phi\rightarrow (1+i\theta)\phi$$

$$\phi^*\rightarrow (1-i\theta)\phi^*$$

Comment: What is the definition of a "small parameter". If it is $\lim_{\theta \to 1} exp (i\theta) $, then this limit goes to $1$, not $i\theta$. How does one get $i\theta$ from $exp(i\theta)$ being "small". It is a Taylor expansion of $\exp (i\theta)$, then taking only the first term ?

Comment: Yes it’s a taylor expansion to first order

Comment: Small meaning Taylor expansion to first order in the parameters, not zero order.

Comment: @Anon21 Small here means $\theta \ll 1$

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in the consequences for $\phi+\delta\phi=e^{i\theta}\phi$ of$$\color{blue}{\delta L=\delta\phi\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi}+\delta\partial_\nu\phi\frac{\partial L}{\partial\partial_\nu\phi}+\delta\phi^\ast\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi^\ast}+\delta\partial_\nu\phi^\ast\frac{\partial L}{\partial\partial_\nu\phi^\ast}}.$$To first order $\delta\phi=i\theta\phi,\,\delta\phi^\ast=-i\theta\phi^\ast$ (because $e^{\pm i\phi}-1\in\pm i\phi+O(\phi^2)$), so the blue equation can be rewritten on-shell as$$\delta L=\delta\phi\partial_\nu\frac{\partial L}{\partial\partial_\nu\phi}+\partial_\nu\delta\phi\frac{\partial L}{\partial\partial_\nu\phi}+\cdots=\partial_\nu\left(\delta\phi\frac{\partial L}{\partial\partial_\nu\phi}+\cdots\right)=-\partial_\nu(\theta j^\nu)$$(where $\cdots$ cover the $\phi^\ast$ parts), and in particular for $\partial_\nu\theta=0$ as $\delta L=-\theta \partial_\nu j^\nu$, with $j^\nu$ as per your formula (proof is an exercise). Such a total derivative formula for $\delta L$ implies an action-preserving exact symmetry. In fact, even $L$ is invariant under $\phi\to e^{i\theta}\phi$ for $\partial_\nu\theta=0$, so $\partial_\nu j^\nu=0$, making $j$ a conserved current. (You can also verify this continuity equation follows from the equations of motion.)

If we repeated this calculation to higher orders in $\theta$, we'd get a $\theta^2$ etc. term in $\delta L$. But since $\partial_\nu j^\nu=0$ is a corollary of the Euler-Lagrange equations, and the exact transformation preserves $L$, the $\theta^2$ etc. coefficients must also be $0$ on-shell. (This doesn't give us "new" on-shell results, though, so much as consequences of earlier ones.) If $L$ were merely invariant up to a total derivative, we'd get such derivatives from the higher-order coefficients.

What's *really* interesting is if we allow $\partial_\nu\theta$ to be non-zero $\delta L$ picks up a term proportional to this derivative, since$$\delta L=-\partial_\nu(\theta j^\nu)=-\theta\underbrace{\partial_\nu j^\nu}_\star-j^\nu\partial_\nu\theta=-j^\nu\partial_\nu\theta$$(recall $\star$ vanishes by the EOMs). Indeed, one way to compute Noether currents is as the $\partial_\nu\theta$ coefficient in $\delta L$ for such "local" generalizations of a global symmetry.